# Find the last non-zero element in a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to find the index of the last non-zero element in a `std::vector<double>`. If the last element in the vector is non-zero then it should return the index of that last element.

I believe I can use `std::find_if_not`, *reverse* iterators and `std::distance`, based on this:

`std::find_if_not(amounts.rbegin(), amounts.rend(), 0.0)`

where `amounts` is a `std::vector<double>`, but I'm having difficulty in combining this with `std::distance` and a forward iterator `amounts.begin()`.

Also, is there a way I can introduce a predicate to compare on, say a tolerance of 1e-8?

I'm using C++11.

Comment: Development time may be faster if you use a simple `for` loop.

Comment: I think I'll get fired if I do that: I need to do this quite a few times.

Comment: Last parameter for [`std::find_if_not`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) should be an unary predicate - you can use lambda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example:

```
std::vector<double> v{1.32, 1.423, 2.543, 3.534, 4.2, 0};

auto result1 = std::find_if(std::rbegin(v), std::rend(v), [](auto& v) { return std::fabs(v - 0) > std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon(); } );
if (result1 != std::rend(v)) {
    std::cout << *result1 << "\n";
    std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(v), (result1 + 1).base());
}
```

outputs:

```
4.2
4
```

[edit]

more explanation on:

```
std::fabs(v - 0) > std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon(); }
```

in OP question there was:

> Also, is there a way I can introduce a predicate to compare on, say a tolerance of 1e-8?

so this is such tolerance check, you can replace `epsilon` use with some other value.

Comment: Some explanations of the code would be useful, that's why I downvoted.

Comment: For me it is useful as it is. Thank you. (The only thing I don't like is the comparison to std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()).

Comment: Do you really understand why he uses `return std::fabs(v - 0) > std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` instead of just `return v != 0` ? You may, but other people looking at the code may not...

Comment: Using epsilon is infact an arbitrary and in fact a poor choice. But the main part of the answer is useful to me.

Comment: I have added some comment on epsilon compare, actually epsilon() might  not be what OP wants, and some other value would be better as it depends on what values are present in this vector.

Comment: @XavierImbs on the other hand, without context, epsilon isn't any more arbitrary or a poor choice than 1e-8 or 0. (But yeah, introducing a new tolerance in the answer might lead a reader to interpret it as something that is "better", when they're all arbitrary).

Comment: I still don't understand `fabs(v - 0)`. Why is it better than `fabs(v)` ?

Comment: Other than the fact that the answerer is explicitly centring the comparison about 0, there isn't.

Comment: yes this `- 0` is not needed, at least for the case as in question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop can also do the trick, see live sample: http://ideone.com/dVNOKk

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0};

    for (int i = static_cast<int>(v.size()) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (v.at(i) != 0) {
            std::cout << "Last non-zero at: " << i << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `Last non-zero at: 12`

Comment: `v.size() - 1` is evaluated in unsigned arithmetic. Not good if the vector is empty.

Comment: @XavierImbs I do not think it does ( http://ideone.com/uuw5PC ) but added cast to clarify.

Comment: Now you limit the supported size of vector by half. Also `v.at(i) != 0` is not good for doubles.

Comment: @luk32 For simplicity I used `int`.

Comment: != 0 is fine for doubles, if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm having difficulty in combining this with std::distance and a forward iterator amounts.begin()

Reverse iterators have member function `base` that returns a non-reverse iterator with the relation `&*(rit.base() - 1) == &*rit`. So, you can use the following:

```
 std::distance(amounts.begin(), found.base()) - 1;
```

Another option:

```
 amounts.size() - std::distance(amounts.rbegin(), found) - 1
```

> Also, is there a way I can introduce a predicate to compare on, say a tolerance of 1e-8?

Yes. In fact, you must use a predicate, even for the exact comparison, since that's what `std::find_if_not` expects as the third parameter (instead of value of an element).